# How spring communicates over network without using serialisable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I was trying to understand the serialisable concept in java, and I got to know whenever there is network call(such as db, http call) serialisation/deserialisation helps us to maintain the structure. And I was advised to implement the serialisable interface to every POJO class.

But when I came to use spring, most of the things work without implementing the serialisable.

Example 1:

```
@Entity  
public class Student {  
    @Id  
    private int id;  
    private String name;  
    private long fees;  
}
```

Now the above entity can be used by data JPA to make a db call without being implemented as serialisable.

Example 2:

```
  @GetMapping("/hello-world")
  @ResponseBody
  public Greeting sayHello(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="Stranger") String name) {
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
  }

}
```

Now you can see in the above controller it is using the Greeting object as a response to  a http get request.

Greeting.java

```
package com.example.actuatorservice;

public class Greeting {

  private final long id;
  private final String content;

  public Greeting(long id, String content) {
    this.id = id;
    this.content = content;
  }

  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public String getContent() {
    return content;
  }

}
```

You can see here too greeting.java is not implementing any serialisable interface.

But the above 2 examples will work perfectly in spring.

Can anybody help me understand this what is happening, should I or should I use the serialisable in spring or not?

Comment: Do you actually know what `Serializable` does in Java? Because your questions suggests you don't actually understand what it's for, otherwise you'd understand that to serialize classes to JSON (or XML), you don't (and generally, shouldn't) have those classes implement `Serializable`. `Serializable` "enables" the Java proprietary binary serialization for that class (using `ObjectOutputStream`/`ObjectInputStream`). It has nothing to do with other forms of serialization.

Comment: JSON/xml (conversion) is (sufficient alternative for) "serialization"

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That's I was asked question because I was not clear, but your answer is not clear either. Can you provide some links that will help me understand like how many types of serialisation are there and details about those?

Comment: It wasn't an answer, it was a comment. If you want to know more about Java serialization, read the Javadoc of `Serializable`, `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`. If you want to know more about JSON serialization, read the documentation of the JSON library you use.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing the `Serializable` interface (and using standard serialization in general) is just one of many ways to transfer data of the wire with Java.

The `Serializable` does literally nothing but mark a class as fit for serialization. Nothing is keeping you or a framework developer from converting any object to a byte stream and sending that over a TCP/IP connection or similar. There are plenty of formats available: (JSON, XML, binary).

Beyond that there are other means, like extracting the relevant values of an object and creating one or more SQL statements out of it in order to store it in a data and using different SQL statement to load the data back and creating instances from it.

In a very abstract way Spring WebMVC works similar. It will convert an object into HTML by finding a template and executing it using the matching template engine.

In the end all is just reflection: finding all the the attributes of an object in order to get it's data and finding constructors and setters to create new instances from data.